# Issues with logging queue and multprocessing

Tags: python, logging, process

In my program, I woudld like to launch several processes and collect the log messages from each process in a single centralized messaging queue.
I created a dedicated class 'LogMaster' which role is to collect the logs from the processes and print them through a stream handler and a file Handler.
Then, I tried to launch processes but there is a mishandling of my logs as they did not print/collect log messages.

Here is my code below, and the outputed result when launching the script.
I tried to identify where the problem come from by inserting debug messages by printing and writing into log file.
"1 - start_process: Print term is working!" but "2 - process_func: Print term is working!" is never displayed and I do not understand why.
I'm begging for your help :)

**Output**

```
[user@mydev dev]$ python main.py
2019-03-06 13:05:12,483 INFO    MyGraph started
1 - start_process: Print term is working!
2019-03-06 13:05:12,483 INFO    1 - start_process: LogMaster.info is working too!
2019-03-06 13:05:12,483 INFO    Start process 'graph.GraphGenerator'
2019-03-06 13:05:12,483 INFO    MyGraph ended
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from logger import set_logging, LogMaster
from graph import GraphGenerator

SERVICE_NAME = 'MyGraph'
set_logging(SERVICE_NAME)
LogMaster.start_logging()
LogMaster.info("{} started".format(SERVICE_NAME ))
service = GraphGenerator()
service.start_process()
LogMaster.info("{} ended".format(SERVICE_NAME))
LogMaster.stop_logging()
```

**graph.py** implements the GraphGenerator() class which will be in charge of launching several processes

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value, Lock
from logger import LogMaster, set_logging
import traceback

class GraphGenerator():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start_process(self):
        LogMaster.print_term("1 - start_process: Print term is working!")
        LogMaster.info("1 - start_process: LogMaster.info is working too!")
        p = Process(target=self.process_func, args=(LogMaster.logging_queue,))
        LogMaster.info("Start process '{}'".format(self.__class__))
        p.start()

    def process_func(self, logging_queue):
        LogMaster.print_term("2 - process_func: Print term is working!")
        LogMaster.info("2 - process_func: LogMaster.info is working too!")
        try:
            LogMaster.set_logging_queue(logging_queue)
            LogMaster.print_term("process_func: Print term is working!")
            LogMaster.info("process_func: LogMaster.info is working too!")

        except Exception as e:
            print("Ex=================")
            LogMaster.info(traceback.format_exc())
```

**logger.py** implement the LogMaster() class in charge of logging

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import logging
from multiprocessing import Queue
from threading import Thread

class LogMaster(object):
    logging_queue = None
    logging_thread = None

    @classmethod
    def start_logging(self):
        # create pipe to centralise messages
        self.logging_queue = Queue()
        self.logging_thread = Thread(target=self.logging_func)
        self.logging_thread.daemon = True
        self.logging_thread.start()

    @classmethod
    def set_logging_queue(self, q):
        self.logging_queue = q

    @classmethod
    def stop_logging(self):
        self.logging_queue.put(None)
        self.logging_thread.join()

    @classmethod
    def print_term(self, msg, end='\n'):
        self.logging_queue.put(("print", msg, end))

    @classmethod
    def log(self, loglevel, msg):
        #print(loglevel, msg)
        self.logging_queue.put(("log", loglevel, msg))

    @classmethod
    def info(self, msg):
        self.log(logging.INFO, msg)

    @classmethod
    def logging_func(self):
        while True:
            item = self.logging_queue.get()
            if item == None:
                break
            elif item[0] == "print":
                print(item[1], end=item[2])
                sys.stdout.flush()
                pass
            elif item[0] == "log":
                logging.log(item[1], item[2])

def set_logging(logfile_name, verbose=False):

    # == General log ==
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # File handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile_name)
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # Stream handler
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    sh.createLock()

    #Formatter
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    sh.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(sh)
```

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with the code you share here. Indentation issues, irrelevant code, calls to functions/methods that don't exist. I'd like to help, but having to fix that code to be able to look into the issue your post is about, is _very_ annoying. Please fix your MCVE.

Comment: I am so sorry for the first version. I wanted to clean the code on the first version posted, however I made some mistake. This new version is tested and is working. Very very sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has a timing issue. `service.start_process()` returns almost immediately; so does `LogMaster.info("{} ended".format(SERVICE_NAME))`. `LogMaster.stop_logging()` is called before the setup of your child process is complete.
 Forking child processes takes time; you tear down your `logging_thread` before the child starts executing. It still does execute, but at that point, there's nothing listening on the queue any more; the messages get lost.

You'll have to come up with a plan where/when to synchronize your processes. A quick fix is to simply add `p.join()` after `p.start()` in `GraphGenerator.start_process`. Not sure if you want your main process to block on the execution of that method, though.
Another option is shown in the code example below.

On POSIX compliant OSs, it's not necessary to pass the queue to `process_func`. On these OSs, childs are created by bascially copying the parent, the LogMaster class object in the child process is a copy of the one in the main process, it has the queue already.

You could refactor your `LogMaster` a bit though. The class itself could be a subclass of `threading.Thread` and the instructions in `set_logging` could be added to `LogMaster` and executed as part of the initialization.
With that, instantiating the class could set up logging and start the listener for the queue, while accessing the static/classmethods on the class itself would simply be used to dispatch the messages.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing
import sys   
from threading import Thread  

class LogMaster(Thread):

    QUEUE = None

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        Thread.__init__(self, name="LoggerThread")
        LogMaster.QUEUE = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self._file_name = file_name
        self._init_logging()
        self.start()

    def _init_logging(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        fh = logging.FileHandler(self._file_name)
        fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        sh = logging.StreamHandler()
        sh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        sh.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(fh)
        self.logger.addHandler(sh)

    def _handle_message(self, message):
        if message[0] == "print":
            print(message[1], end=message[2])
            sys.stdout.flush()
        elif message[0] == "log":
            self.logger.log(message[1], message[2])

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = LogMaster.QUEUE.get()
            if message is None:
                break
            else:
                self._handle_message(message)

    def shutdown(self):
        LogMaster.QUEUE.put(None)
        try:
            self.join(2)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

    @classmethod
    def _log(cls, loglevel, msg):
        cls.QUEUE.put(("log", loglevel, msg))

    @classmethod
    def print_term(cls, msg, end='\n'):
        cls.QUEUE.put(("print", msg, end))

    @staticmethod
    def info(msg):
        LogMaster._log(logging.INFO, msg)
```

**graph.py**

```
import traceback
from multiprocessing import Process
from logger import LogMaster

class GraphGenerator:

    def start_process(self):
        LogMaster.print_term("1 - start_process: Print term is working!")
        LogMaster.info("1 - start_process: LogMaster.info is working too!")
        p = Process(target=self.process_func)
        LogMaster.info("starting '{}'".format(self.__class__))
        p.start()
        # maybe you want to start several processes quickly and rather block
        # your main process to wait for them there.
        return p

    def process_func(self):
        LogMaster.print_term("2 - process_func: Print term is working!")
        LogMaster.info("2 - process_func: LogMaster.info is working too!")
        try:
            raise ValueError("checking the exception handling")
        except ValueError:
            LogMaster.info(traceback.format_exc())
```

**main.py**

```
from graph import GraphGenerator
from logger import LogMaster

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    SERVICE_NAME = 'MyGraph'
    lm = LogMaster(SERVICE_NAME)
    LogMaster.info("{} started".format(SERVICE_NAME))
    service = GraphGenerator()
    child = service.start_process()
    # start more child processes if needed
    # once all are started, wait for them to complete in the main process
    child.join()
    LogMaster.info("{} ended".format(SERVICE_NAME))
    lm.shutdown()
```

**Output**

```
[shmee@massive test]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
# ======================================
[shmee@massive test]$ python main.py
2019-03-07 12:28:23,425 INFO    MyGraph started
1 - start_process: Print term is working!
2019-03-07 12:28:23,425 INFO    1 - start_process: LogMaster.info is working too!
2019-03-07 12:28:23,425 INFO    starting 'graph.GraphGenerator'
2 - process_func: Print term is working!
2019-03-07 12:28:23,426 INFO    2 - process_func: LogMaster.info is working too!
2019-03-07 12:28:23,426 INFO    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shmee/test/graph.py", line 21, in process_func
    raise ValueError("checking the exception handling")
ValueError: checking the exception handling

2019-03-07 12:28:23,428 INFO    MyGraph ended
# ======================================    
[shmee@massive test]$ cat MyGraph
2019-03-07 12:28:23,425 INFO    MyGraph started
2019-03-07 12:28:23,425 INFO    1 - start_process: LogMaster.info is working too!
2019-03-07 12:28:23,425 INFO    starting 'graph.GraphGenerator'
2019-03-07 12:28:23,426 INFO    2 - process_func: LogMaster.info is working too!
2019-03-07 12:28:23,426 INFO    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shmee/test/graph.py", line 21, in process_func
    raise ValueError("checking the exception handling")
ValueError: checking the exception handling

2019-03-07 12:28:23,428 INFO    MyGraph ended
# ======================================    
# this works as well
[shmee@massive test]$ ../source/python-3.6.4.el7.x86_64/bin/python3 main.py
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, very clear and complete